# I want to check the username is already exists in my database table or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net, 3-tier

i have registration page and i want to check that username is already exist in database or not in 3 tier architecture.

**MyRegistration.cs:**

```
public static int checkusername(string user_txt)
 {
  int id2 = 0;
  string selectstr = "select * from xyz where UserName = '" + user_txt + " ' ";
  id2 = DataAccessLayer.ExecuteReader(selectstr);
  return id2;    
 }
```

and the code behind **onclick event of textbox**:

```
protected void txt_username_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_username.Text))
   {
    int id = xyz.checkusername(txt_username.Text.Trim());
    if (id > 0)
     {
      lblStatus.Text = "UserName Already Taken";
     }
    else
     {
      lblStatus.Text = "UserName Available";
     }
   } 

 }
```

**DataAccessLayer:**

```
public static int ExecuteReader(string Query)
 {
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
  con.ConnectionString = GetConnectionString();
  con.Open();
  int id = 0;            
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
  cmd.CommandText = Query;
  cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
  cmd.Connection = con;
  SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  while (reader.Read())
   {
    id++;
   }
  cmd = null;
  reader.Close();
  con.Close();
  return id;
 }
```

Comment: so what is the doubt here???

Comment: Beware of SQL injections with this!

Comment: You're opening up some security risks like this, you need to prevent SQL injections. edit: looks like keysharpener beat me!

Comment: So what doesn't work about this?

Comment: this is code is not working i think there is some problem in onclick event can you give me another code ?

Comment: *How*? Be specific. Any exceptions? Silent error? Makes your computer blow up? What do you do to get it to 'not work'? *How*?

Comment: "Not working" doesn't tell us much. *How* is this code not working? What happens when you run it? What's the error message?

Comment: its allowing same username multiple times

Comment: @yash : Can you paste the code that you written on the function DataAccessLayer.ExecuteReader(String SqlQuery) ? then it will help us to solve the issue...

Comment: @Pandian check it dude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have edited some of your codes try like below... it will help you...

**Text change Event :**

```
    protected void txt_username_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_username.Text))
        {
            if (xyz.checkusername(txt_username.Text.Trim()))
            {
                lblStatus.Text = "UserName Already Taken";
            }
            else
            {
                lblStatus.Text = "UserName Available";
            }
        }

    }
```

**Check Username :**

```
    public bool CheckUsername(string user_txt)
    {
        bool Result;
        Result = DataAccessLayer.ExecuteReader(user_txt);
        return Result;
    }
```

**Excute Reader :**

```
    public bool ExecuteReader(string user_txt)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = GetConnectionString();
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from xyz where UserName = @UserID", con);
        SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@UserID";
        param.Value = user_txt;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually if the "select query" doesn't find a userName with the parameter user_txt you'll id2 will be end up with the value -1. So the appropriate code would be:

```
           if (id ==-1)
               {
                   lblStatus.Text = "UserName Available";
               }
           if (id>0)
               {

                   lblStatus.Text = "UserName Already Taken";
               }
```

By the way, your code is highly insecure and your database can be easily attacked using [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) I'd recommend you to understand this issue and add parameters to the query to prevent it. C# has its ways to implement this. Don't try to fix the access to the database, just start from scrath keeping in mind SQL Injection.

Comment: you'll need to correct the "selectstr" as the other comments said

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, this approach has potentially serious security issues.

However, your problem may lie here `user_txt + " ' "`. The spaces around the second `'`, specifically the one before it may lead to the usernames not matching as expected.